# how to make :hover height to not move object under it

Tags: html, css, hover, width

I have this fiddle : `jsfiddle.net/kxmzqbtL/`

How can I make that the elements above other elements dont move these under them.
@fiddle : when hovering first three childs, it moves 4th and 5th child to fix its hover /width/ effect. How can I make it overlay these elements insted of moving them? Or other way to make it looks better, like scale first element up instead of down.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to the .item:hover:

```
margin-bottom: -15%;
z-index: 1;
```

Negative margin will make items placed below go up instead of down (so in this case it will negate added height and items will stay in the same place).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kxmzqbtL/2/

Comment: Thank you! :) and why the z-index is in there?

Comment: It says that this item should be displayed above other items. By default items which are placed later in DOM tree are displayed above former items. So your item with changed width would be partially covered by items below. Just see what happens when you delete this line to understand. Also see: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Comment: Thanks, I though that z-index only works with position:absolute, thanks for explain.